# Interaction in glmer (stats advice)

Tags: lme4, interaction

I need help understanding and following up an interaction obtained using glmer() from lme4.

The data comes from a language processing experiment that studies the effects of three categorical variables (control/copula/gender) on a binomial response (preferred or dispreferred). Each of the experimental factors have two levels: 
control (subject/object)
copula (ser/estar) 
gender (masculine/feminine).

I run the following model:

```
model1= glmer(preferences~control*copula*gender+(1|participant), family=binomial, data=data2)
```

And these are the results I obtained:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: preferences_narrow ~ control * copula * gender + (1 | participant)
   Data: data2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1208.6   1261.1   -595.3   1190.6     2517 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.6567  0.1970  0.2337  0.2883  0.5371 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 0.254    0.504   
Number of obs: 2526, groups:  participant, 105

Fixed effects:
                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           2.5034     0.2147  11.660  < 2e-16 ***
controlsubject                        0.4882     0.3172   1.539  0.12380    
copulaser                             0.4001     0.3237   1.236  0.21646    
gendermasc                           -0.4524     0.2659  -1.701  0.08888 .  
controlsubject:copulaser             -1.0355     0.4526  -2.288  0.02215 *  
controlsubject:gendermasc             0.5790     0.4430   1.307  0.19121    
copulaser:gendermasc                  1.7343     0.5819   2.980  0.00288 ** 
controlsubject:copulaser:gendermasc  -1.3121     0.7540  -1.740  0.08181 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) cntrls coplsr gndrms cntrlsbjct:c cntrlsbjct:g cplsr:
contrlsbjct  -0.602                                                      
copulaser    -0.588  0.401                                               
gendermasc   -0.724  0.488  0.479                                        
cntrlsbjct:c  0.415 -0.701 -0.716 -0.342                                 
cntrlsbjct:g  0.432 -0.716 -0.287 -0.599  0.502                          
cplsr:gndrm   0.332 -0.223 -0.556 -0.457  0.397        0.274             
cntrlsbjc::  -0.252  0.421  0.430  0.352 -0.600       -0.588       -0.772
```

There are two significant interactions `controlsubject:copulaser`  and `copulaser:gendermasc`.

I followed up on the first interaction using emmeans:

```
emmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ control + copula), adjust = "tukey")
```

The results seem to show that multiple contrasts are driving the interaction (something similar happens when I do the same for the second interaction):

```
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
$`emmeans of control, copula`
 control copula   emmean        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 object  estar  2.277256 0.1497913 Inf  1.983670  2.570841
 subject estar  3.054906 0.1912774 Inf  2.680009  3.429802
 object  ser    3.544448 0.2697754 Inf  3.015698  4.073198
 subject ser    2.630568 0.1752365 Inf  2.287110  2.974025

Results are averaged over the levels of: gender 
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$`pairwise differences of control, copula`
 contrast                       estimate        SE  df z.ratio p.value
 object,estar - subject,estar -0.7776499 0.2215235 Inf  -3.510  0.0025
 object,estar - object,ser    -1.2671927 0.2910689 Inf  -4.354  0.0001
 object,estar - subject,ser   -0.3533119 0.2088155 Inf  -1.692  0.3279
 subject,estar - object,ser   -0.4895427 0.3138092 Inf  -1.560  0.4017
 subject,estar - subject,ser   0.4243380 0.2396903 Inf   1.770  0.2877
 object,ser - subject,ser      0.9138807 0.3048589 Inf   2.998  0.0145

Results are averaged over the levels of: gender 
Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

Yet, what does the NOTE mean?

```
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
```

Is this a good procedure to follow up these interactions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the annotations, the estimates shown are averages of predictions for combinations of control, copula, and gender, averaged over gender. Meanwhile, the model includes interactions between gender and the other two factors, which suggests that those averages may not be meaningful. You can visualize this by constructing a plot of the 3-way predictions:

```
emmip(model1, gender ~ control * copula)
```

If the predictions compare quite differently from one case to the next, then the averages of them would be nonsense. But if they compare pretty much the same, then it would be ok to average them. That’s what the warning is about.

Im guessing that you *do* meet to worry about the interactions with gender — in which case you should do the comparisons separately:

```
emmeans(model1, pairwise ~ control * copula | gender)
```